# Return JavaScript value in Swift

Tags: javascript, swift, macos, wkwebview, javascriptcore

I need to return a value in Swift by executing JavaScript, but I am having trouble I have searched everywhere, but I can't find anything that works. To execute the JavaScript, I am using

```
webby.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelector(\"pre\").innerText;")
```

(Webby is the name of the web view)
The JavaScript returns a string, which I would like to access in Swift.  How would I accomplish this?  Thanks.

Comment: If you took the JavaScript you have in quotes: `document.querySelector(\"pre\").innerText` and run it in JavaScript it won't do anything.  Perhaps you need a `return` statement before it `return document.querySelector(\"pre\").innerText`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access the value you have to provide a completion handler to `evaluateJavaScript`, see the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript):

```
webby.evaluateJavaScript("<your code goes here>") { result, error in
  if let result = result {
    // your result handling goes here
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to return a dummy value to see if your setup works at all, e.g. `"return 'foo'"`. If you then get `foo` in your handler you know that the problem is in your JS code.